# During covid, can a filipino citizen allowed to have a connecting flight from japan to india?

Tags: air-travel, transit, japan, covid-19, filipino-citizens

Im a filipino citizen with business visa travelling to india as my final distination but with stop over in japan through a connecting flight. I heard many restrictions between countries to countries during covid in airports, my question is' can a filipino citizen are allowed to have a connecting flight from japan to india during  covid 19'?  Right now there are no direct flights from Philippines to india and still negotiating the air bubble arrangement between 2 countries,
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a filipino citizen are allowed to have a connecting flight from japan to india during covid 19

Yes. Japan has no COVID-19-related transit restrictions aside from NRT transits having to be on the same calendar day. Also you can't enter Japan (i.e., must transit in the same airport, e.g. you can't do NRT->HND transit). See https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> Japan.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is awesome, never heard about timatic, we found another route hopefully, thanks a lot.