# Can a US Citizen transit through a COVID restricted country to a non restricted country?

Tags: air-travel, transit, us-citizens, layovers, covid-19

There are several countries that are open to US Citizens for travel. However, getting to them may require transiting through a country that does not allow entry. Example: Flying to Namibia via a layover in Germany. Germany currently does not allow US Travel, but Namibia does.

Does anyone know if US Citizens can transit (without leaving the airport) through countries that restrict travel due to COVID?

Comment: I would say this is too broad to answer properly, especially since the rules keep changing every week.

Comment: Note that even if the US citizen does not leave the airport, the virus he could have brought with him may leave the airport through staff, other passengers,... so it may depend on the local safety measures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does anyone know if US Citizens can transit (without leaving the airport) through countries that restrict travel due to COVID?

That depends on the transit country. Some ban transit (e.g., [Thailand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/161174/1810)), some don't, and some allow transit with some restrictions (e.g., [Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/161009/1810), [Philippines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158885/1810)). See https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm to get the information for each country.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The policy of the destination country is also relevant. For instance, the US does non allow non-exempt travellers to transit through banned countries.